# Adding entities with Id 0 using EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I'm trying to update an ICollection Navigation property called Tags, which belong to the User entity:

```
if (memberUpdateDto.Tags != null)
{
    user.Tags = new List<UsersTags>();
    foreach (TagDto tagDto in memberUpdateDto.Tags)
    {
      user.Tags.Add(new UsersTags
      {
         AppUserId = user.Id,
         TagId = tagDto.Value
      });
     }
 }
```

Where UserTags connects between User and Tags:

```
public class UsersTags
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int AppUserId { get; set; }
   public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
   public int TagId { get; set; }
   public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

This gives the next error:

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.
```

Which I believe is caused because UsersTags' Id is 0.
As the code implies, I want to delete the old ones, and just add new ones, how do I tell EF to ignore that Id, and just add new?
As per Serge's answer - I would like to avoid creating another repository, but rather update the navigation properties as a part of the User entity (I believe that's possible).

My Tags:
Id  CreatorId   IsApproved  Text
1   NULL    1   SQL
2   NULL    1   Python
3   NULL    1   React
4   NULL    1   Angular

Comment: The Id of ``UserTags`` is auto increment?

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad Yes

Comment: The says ``FOREIGN KEY constraint failed``, have you inserted ``Tags`` before insert UserTags?

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad Yes.

Comment: So, you have multiple UserTags with Id=0 and because the UserTags.Id is the primary key it must not duplicated, you want to insert it anyway?

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad yes, I want to insert it as new

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241129/discussion-between-oren-a-and-saeed-esmaeelinejad).

Comment: The messages 'error while updating' could point to a `user.Tags` update issue. Probably, this collection is not empty and the code tries to overwrite it (update). Re-initialization is not a proper way to clear the navigated properties for EF. Items there should be disconnected explicitly. Presume, that collection is not empty (its Entity ctor initializes it). If so, then replace `user.Tags = new List<UsersTags>()` with `user.Tags.Clear();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var  newUserTags = new List<UsersTags>();

if (memberUpdateDto.Tags != null)
{
      foreach (TagDto tagDto in memberUpdateDto.Tags)
    {
      newUserTags.Add(new UsersTags
      {
         AppUserId = user.Id,
         TagId = tagDto.Value
      });
     }
 }  
var prevUserTags=context.UserTags.Where(i=>i.UserId=user.Id).ToList();

if ( prevUserTags!=null && prevUserTags.Count > 0 ) context.UserTags.RemoveRange(prevUserTags);

 if ( newUserTags.Count > 0 ) context.UserTags.AddRange(newUserTags);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks, was trying to avoid creating a repository for UserTags though

Comment: @OrenA Where do you see repository for `UserTags` here? If you mean you don't have `UserTags` property in your `DbContext` derived class, just replace `context.UserTags` with `context.Set<UsersTags>()`. Other than that, Serge's answer is correct - EF Core won't replace the existing records automatically, so you have to manually delete the old ones. However, the exception message is referring to FK constraint violation, so it is unlikely the problem is `Id` property - most likely some of `user.Id` or `tagDto.Value` are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to assign AppUserId in your loop, since it adds the Tags to specified users, thus the correct version would be:

```
foreach (TagDto tagDto in memberUpdateDto.Tags)
{
  user.Tags.Add(new UsersTags
  {
     TagId = tagDto.Value
  });
 }
```

And if you want to remove the previous records you only need to write this line  before the loop:

```
context.Set<UsersTags>().RemoveRange(user.Tags);
```